# ajax not working in my rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to add an effect to my rails project using ajax. There's 4 divs on my page:

```
<div header></div>
<div menu></div>
<div content></div>
<div footer></div>
```

When a link in the menu div is clicked, the footer should slide up, and the new page text should appear in the content div. The code works fine when I have all the files in my public folder, in the rails project, but when I put files in the View folders, it doesn't work. Any idea why?

I have a scripts.js file in my assets/javascripts folder. The code is:

```
  var ajax_loaded = (function(response) {               
  $("#content").slideUp(                            
    "fast",                                         
    function() {                                    
        $("#content")                           
            .html(response)                         
            .slideDown("fast");                     

        $("#content .ajax").on("click",ajax_load);  
        $("#content form").on("submit",form_submit);
    });
});

var form_submit = (function(e) {                    
    e.preventDefault();                             

    var url = $(this).attr("action");               
    var method = $(this).attr("method");            


    var data = {}                                   
    $(this).find("input, textarea").each(function(i){
        var name = $(this).attr("name");            
        var value = $(this).val();                  

        data[name] =value;                          

    }); 

    $.ajax({                                        
        "url": url,                                 
        "type": method,                             
        "data": data,                               
        "success": function () {                    
            history.pop();                          
            $(history.pop()).trigger("click");      
        },
        "error": function () {alert("bad");}        
    });
});


var history = [];                                   

var current_url_method;                             

var ajax_load = (function(e) {                      
    e.preventDefault();                             


    history.push(this);                             

    var url =$(this).attr("href");                  
    var method = $(this).attr("data-method");       

    if (current_url_method != url + method) {       
        current_url_method = url + method;          

        $.ajax({                                    
            "url": url,                             
            "type": method,                         
            "success": ajax_loaded,                 
        });
     }
});

$("#menu a").on("click",ajax_load);                 
$("#menu a.main").trigger("click");
```

I have a style.css.scss in my assets/stylesheets folder. The code is:

```
#header {
    background: #333333;
    height:50px;
}

     #menu {
      background: #ffffff;

      }

#content { background: #eeeeee;height:100px;}
#footer {
    background: #333333;
    color: #ffffff;
    height: 100px;
}
```

In my routes folder I have:

```
 Books::Application.routes.draw do

  get "about_us", :to => "static_pages#about_us"
  get "contact_us", :to => "static_pages#contact_us"
  get "invite_us", :to => "static_pages#invite"
  get "faq", :to => "static_pages#faq"

  root :to => 'books#index'
```

Index method in the Books controller is:

```
def index
render :layout => "application"
end
```

In my Views/layouts, in application.html.erb, I have (this change a bit from my public folder, where links were of the form `<a href = "/about.html" class = "main">About Us</a>)`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Books</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<div id = "header">My header</div>
<div id = "menu">
          <%= link_to "About Us",about_us_path,:class => "main" %>
          <%= link_to "FAQ", faq_path, :class => "main" %>
          <%= link_to "Invite Others", invite_us_path, :class => "main" %>
          <%= link_to "Contact Us", contact_us_path, :class => "main" %>
</div>

<div id = "content">
<%= yield %>
</div>

<div id = "footer">My footer</div>

<script src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyway, if you have any ideas on what's wrong, I'd be grateful, thanks. Like I said, it wokrs in the public folder, so I think my scripts.js is ok. Could it be something to do with the ':class => "main" ' part?

Comment: When the code works in your `public` folder, what files are you using?

Comment: Hi Summea, I'm using index.html (which contains my application.html.erb code), scripts.js, style.css, about.html, contact_us.html, home.html

Comment: When you run your app as normal (with Rails) are you seeing any JavaScript errors in your browser?  *(I see that you wrote that the JavaScript works when run in the `public` folder... but just wondering about if something ends up going missing that might show up in the JavaScript console.)* :)

Comment: Hi, no, there are no errors in my console - I'm using Google Chrome. The links work, but it just loads the contents in the Contents div - there's no sliding effect.

Comment: Interesting; have you checked to see if there is any noticeable difference in the HTML page (generated with your Rails app) vs your HTML page (when your files are just in your `public` folder)?  Other than that... I wonder if the `response` coming back is different when being run in the app vs being run in the `public` folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it sorted. I wrapped all the code in my scripts.js in a

```
$(document).on("ready", function(){......});
```

That was the main thing.

Also, I was calling the jquery library twice, which probably didn't help - //= require jquery, in my application.js.erb file, and also from  my application.html.erb.

Anyway, the case is resolved! Thanks for everything.

Comment: Ah! Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to make sure scripts.js is being served when you load the page. I see that you include application.js in your layout file. This file is used as a manifest file in the Rails asset pipeline, so make sure it's configured to include scripts.js when it loads. It will need to have a line like this:

```
//= require scripts
```

In a browser, assuming you are running a rails server on port 3000, you can make sure your scripts file is accessible by visiting `http://localhost:3000/assets/scripts.js`. You can make sure it's included in application.js by visiting `http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js`.

More information on the asset pipeline: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks. scripts.js is there and I did put in //=require scripts in my application.js.erb file. Is the erb extension ok? But when I put http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js in the browser, the code is different to application.js.erb I put require details into. That right?

Comment: I haven't used erb within asset-pipelined javascript, but according to the documentation, you can do that. When you load up application.js in the browser, do you see the javascript from scripts.js? Is your `ajax_loaded` function there along with the rest of that file? I do not see any other obvious area to check in your code, but I'll give it another read. Let me know if you have this in a github repo I could clone and debug.

Comment: Hi, in my application.js.erb file I can see my ajax_loaded function, as well as the rest of the scripts.js file. But I can't see my 'require scripts' code anywhere. There's no 'require' any file, in fact.